# When saving Open Office files they used to stay Open Office files, now they change to Terminal files

Tags: macos, terminal

It used to be that when I saved Open Office files they would stay Open Office files. Now, they change to Terminal files, as it keeps opening in my dock.

How can I remove or stop Terminal opening (I'm running a Macbook Air '11)?

I'm so used to seeing my writing in Open Office files!

Answer (score 1):

Select any one of those Open Office files in a Finder window. Hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open up the information window for that file. Near the bottom of that window you should see a pane that says "Open with:".

[image: infodialogue]

If it says "Terminal," then click on the dialogue to bring up a drop-down menu, which will present you with a list of applications usually associated with that type of file. Find "Open Office" in the list and select it. You *may* have to scroll to the bottom to select "other..." if Open Office isn't listed.

[image: dropdown]

After you've selected "Open Office," the <kbd>Change All...</kbd> button should be active. Hit "Change All..." and you will be asked to confirm if you want to open all file types with that application. Confirm the choice and you should be good to go.